# Where is the failed Medi-Gel Experiment during the the "N7: Cerberus Labs" mission?

Tags: mass-effect-3

I know there's a "failed Medi-Gel Experiment" somewhere during the "N7: Cerberus Labs", but I can't seem to find it anywhere. **Where is the failed experiment located in the level?** I'm trying to kick off the related quest; I just need to find the starting point first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The medi-gel is located at the end of a corridor on the right on the upper floor, on a console.

[image]

You can watch the mission walk through [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aXl0o5qY360) (medi gel around 8:30), or the short version [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9haszZuTqqM)

Answer (score 0):

It is located on one of the consoles on the topmost level. Accessing it like any other console will give you the Medi-Gel experiment.

Comment: Depending on which route you take, you'll probably pass it to get to the second Prothean artifact.  I actually thought it may have been a third Prothean artifact that I may have had to pick up.  If memory serves me, when you leave the drop zone, go right, and then left, and it will be in a sort of control room on your right.